# Django doesn't seem to work with some python flags

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

When running starting a Django server with `python manage.py runserver`, I want it to catch if there is a BytesWarning in my code. Specifying the `-b` or `-bb` flag usually does it in python, eg. `python -bb somefile.py`. If there is code such as `'b'==b'b'` or `str(b'b')`, a BytesWarning will be given, and the flag makes the interpreter treat it like an error.

However in Django, running `python -bb manage.py runserver` will not cause the BytesWarnings to be caught as an exception in any file except the settings file. For example, I put `'b'==b'b'` in a view, and it doesn't bring up a BytesWarning. It doesn't seem to be any configuration settings for the project that are causing this, as I tried this out in the simple app that we make in the Django tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/, and it still doesn't work.

I'm current using Django 2.1.7, though I did try it in 1.11.20 with no luck. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Never used that flag so not sure how it works but I suppose the code should run for the error to happen, are you visiting the view that has the code that should error?

Comment: Yes I am. The code where it's placed is definitely being executed, yet the warning is not being raised.